# Does a hidden UIViewController consume any resources (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, resources, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller

My simple iPhone game has two basic "screens":

1. home screen (UIViewController subclass)
2. game screen (UIWindow w/ EAGLLayer where all the OpenGL drawing happens)

Currently when the user taps "Play" on the homescreen the UIViewController is just hidden and the game screen is revealed.  When the game is over the homescreen UIViewController is unhidden.

**Does the hidden UIViewController consume any resources when it's hidden?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it consumes some memory because the object exists and iOS needs to store it somewhere in the memory. However, it will **not** consume CPU processing time for rendering it to the UI

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, it is created, so it does consume system resources. I cant tell you how many, depends on the specific situation